# Storing Editor Templates in external library

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, editortemplates

Is it possible to create Editor Templates in an external library so that they can be shared between applications?  I'm not looking to store cshtml files in a library, just wondering if there was a way you can create them and store them like you do with html helpers.  There are a few that i use quite a lot and it would be nice to have them all in a single library to reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MVCContrib Portable Areas](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib.aspx) offers this functionality. Out of the box there is nothing built-in. You will need to roll your custom [VirtualPathProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx) if you wanted to embed views into a separate assembly. You may also find the [following blog post](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/#axzz1FM8sN8gb) useful.