# Is possible to move Custom EditorTemplates from MVC view to c# class Library project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have MVC 5 project in that project I was created some custom EditorTemplates template and strore it into views/shared folder location.

I want to reuse that EditorTemplates into some other MVC 5 project. So I plane to create on class library project and place that EditorTemplates into library project. So that I can reuse it.

But I don't its possible to create EditorTemplates from class library.

for example
I have view model for checkbox like below

```
 public class CheckboxModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Checked { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I have custom EditorTemplate like bellow

```
@model CheckboxModel
@{ 
    <div class="@ViewData["class"]">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(it => it.Checked, new { @class = "with-font" })
        <span>@Html.HiddenFor(it => it.Id)</span>
        @Html.LabelFor(it => it.Checked, Model.Name)
    </div>
}
```

How can I create helper function for this?

Comment: Refer [this article](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Editor Templates in external library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155413/storing-editor-templates-in-external-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write class of `Html` helper functions. It will be an extension methods for `HtmlHelper` class and their result will be `MvcHtmlString`

Comment: I update my question , How can I solved my problem by using your idea.